# UINavigationController - get interactive pop gesture recognizer progress

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have TabBarController which has custom center button (UIButton). The goal here is to animate its opacity when user is returning from other ViewControllers to TabBarController.

So what am I trying to achieve is start animating center button's opacity from 0 to 1, depending on how "far" user has swiped.
I am using `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`, so detecting swipe from edge "progress" would be ideal for my case.

Or is there any other way? Maybe detecting topViewController visibility?

Comment: @BangOperator It is UIButton not UITabBarItem.

Comment: @BangOperator UITabBarController is root. It has many children which all have their own UINavigationController. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this by adding a custom target

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CountdownsViewController.handlePopGesture))
```

and then

```
@objc func handlePopGesture ()
{
    viewtoanimate.alpha = self.transitionCoordinator!.percentComplete
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a middle value of the swipe progress,try this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> t = self.transitionCoordinator;
    BOOL b = [t animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        aCustomView.alpha = 1.f;
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {

    }];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> t = self.transitionCoordinator;
    BOOL b = [t animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        aCustomView.alpha = 0.f;
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationControllerDelegate` has this delegate method

```
- (nullable id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                          interactionControllerForAnimationController:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>) animationController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

You can call this method on you navigation controllers delegate to get an instance of `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`. This class object has a property

```
@property (readonly) CGFloat percentComplete;
```

Use this to find the percent of transition done.

Comment: Nice, looks promising.
Any idea how can I get UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition instance from delegate function?